# NSBitmapImageRep for iPhone (Or direct pixel access for CGImage)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a good analog to `NSBitmapImageRep` in UIKit? Specifically I'm looking for similar methods to [`setPixel:atX:y:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBitmapImageRep/setPixel:atX:y:) and [`getPixel:atX:y:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBitmapImageRep/getPixel:atX:y:). I have found [this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2007/qa1509.html) technote, and it does get me most of the way there using CGImage, but how do I know what order the pixels are in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CGImageGetBitsPerComponent( image );
CGImageGetBitsPerPixel( image );
CGImageGetBytesPerRow( image );
CGImageGetBitmapInfo( image );
CGColorSpaceGetModel( CGImageGetColorSpace( image ) );
CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents( CGImageGetColorSpace( image ) );
```

Using the above calls, you can figure out how each pixel is laid out.  Each pixel for x,y will start at:

```
length = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(image)/CHAR_BIT;
offset = y*CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image) + x*length;
```

A typical 32 bit ARGB PNG might be:

```
8 = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent( image );
32 = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel( image );
kCGImageAlphaFirst = CGImageGetBitmapInfo( image );
4 = CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents( CGImageGetColorSpace( image ) );
kCGColorSpaceModelRGB = CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents( CGImageGetColorSpace( image ) );
```

Comment: Is there a possibility of a non-RGB layout? That was the main thing I was worried about, assuming that every image I find will be RGB.

Comment: Yes, use CGColorSpaceGetModel if you do not know the color space.