# What can I use instead of NSBitmapImageRep in iOS? (Water ripples example)

Tags: ios, swift, cgimage, nsbitmapimagerep

I found this interesting [post about water ripple simulation](http://benbritten.com/2009/05/19/fun-with-unity/). It includes a [Xcode project](http://benbritten.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/bbrippletest.zip) with a little cocoa app for OSX. I tried to get the app running in iOS using Swift, but I couldn't find a solution to the following problem:

The OSX app uses `NSBitmapImageRep` to draw bitmap data from an array onto the screen (this happens in the BBRippleView.m). Unfortunately, `NSBitmapImageRep` is not available in iOS. I tried using a `CGImage` instead, which is "kind of working": I can see some kind of water ripples, but they are split up in some weird way and they don't move the way they are supposed to. I guess the CGImage expects to get the bitmap data in a different format than it currently gets it.

Edit: Here is my iOS RippleView class: [RippleView.swift](http://pastebin.com/pNqYxJFy)

Edit 2: Modified [RippleView.swift](http://pastebin.com/bWCmEsPn)

What would be the right way to implement the following OSX code segments in iOS using Swift?

```
        image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(cols, rows)];
        bufrep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
                            initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                            pixelsWide:cols
                            pixelsHigh:rows
                            bitsPerSample:8
                            samplesPerPixel:1
                            hasAlpha:NO
                            isPlanar:YES
                            colorSpaceName:NSDeviceWhiteColorSpace
                            bytesPerRow:0
                            bitsPerPixel:0];
        [image addRepresentation:bufrep];
```

And

```
-(void)applyBuffer
{
    unsigned char* data = [bufrep bitmapData];
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int position = 0;
    for ( y = 0; y < rows; y ++) {
        for ( x = 0; x < cols ; x ++) {
            position = (y * cols) + x;
            data[position] = (char)buffer2[position] << 1;
        }           
    }       
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you wrote to create your bitmap, modify it, and turn it into a `CGImage` on iOS.

Comment: added the RippleView.swift file

Comment: [NSBitmapImageRep for iPhone, or direct pixel access for CGImage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3142178), or are you looking more for debugging help? If the latter, please edit your title to be more specific to the problem you have with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling `CGImageCreate` that your image is greyscale, with 8 bits by pixel. But your buffers are arrays of `Int`s, which are either 32 or 64 bits (4 or 8 bytes).

Switch to `UInt8`, that should help a lot.

Comment: Now it works much better, but still not the way it's supposed to be (as shown in the video). I added my new RippleView.swift file above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How exactly is is not working as supposed? Please provide an exact description (and/or video) of what you expect and what you get. A quick test shows it apparently working correctly.

Comment: The waves appear to not be as strong/high as in the video. I guess this is because I am using `UInt8` instead of `Int`, which is used in the OSX app: I can only have numbers from 0 to 255 instead of higher values and negative values aswell. Does that make sense?

Comment: The original OSX code uses `Int` buffers, and then converts them to `Int8`-equivalent data (in `applyBuffers`) before display, while in your iOS code you use the buffer directly. You'll probably have to do the same thing. I smell `Int8` overflow lurking, though.